# Path integral of 1/z

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration

Consider the path $ γ:[2π,5π]→ \mathbb{C} $ given by $ γ(t)=te^{it}. $

what is $$ \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} dz $$ 
Using the definition of integral of a complex function over a path?

I got as an answer: $ log \frac{5}{2} +3\pi i $ but aparently that's wrong. I used the integral $ \int_{2\pi}^{5\pi} $ but in the solution they used $\int_{\pi}^{4\pi} $. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since\begin{align}\int_\gamma\frac1z\,\mathrm dz&=\int_{2\pi}^{5\pi}i+\frac1t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\log\left(\frac52\right)+3\pi i,\end{align}your answer is correct. Since $\gamma$ is not periodic, it makes no sense to use $[\pi,4\pi]$ instead of $[2\pi,5\pi]$.